# Extract Information from Clipboard and return partial Information back to Clipboard

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file, clipboard

I'm need a small batch-file which should help me extract an Information from the clipboard an return a partial information to the clipboard.
I have come so far:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set /a count = 0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command "Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html"') do (
    set /a count += 1
    if !count!==8 (
        echo %%a
    )
)
endlocal
```

the `echo %%a` returns this info:

```
<A href='eASEE:DCT_MFA2,1488932'>20210421a_AU42_L2_d2h421bt06ux_eisende.PAR; 0 (PAR)</A>
```

I need the `1488932` back into the clipboard.
Any suggestions?

**Update 22.04.**

I tested the postet answer from `It Wasn't me`, but the result is `nothing`.
Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.
I updated the batch file to:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off  
set /a count = 0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command "Get-Clipboard -TextFormatTypeHtml"') do (
set /a count += 1
echo %%a
)
endlocal
```

The return, if I run it in cmd is:

```
C:\Users\*******\Desktop>test.bat
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000097
EndHTML:00000260
StartFragment:00000111
EndFragment:00000224
<html><body>
<--StartFragment -->
<A href='eASEE:DCT_MFA2,1488932'>20210421a_AU42_L2_d2h421bt06ux_eisende.PAR; 0 (PAR)</A>
<--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Now i just need the `1488932` back into the clipboard to use it elsewhere.

Comment: I made an error above. the returnded value from %aa is 
<A href='eASEE:DCT_MFA2,1488932'>20210421a_AU42_L2_d2h421bt06ux_eisende.PAR; 0 (PAR)</A>

Comment: It would be much easier to do this straight in powershell.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

powershell -nOp -c "$(gcb|%%{$_.split('\''>*.,')[2]})|scb"
```

---

- Strings in my clipboard and **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** job...

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000097
EndHTML:00000260
StartFragment:00000111
EndFragment:00000224
<html><body>
<--StartFragment -->
<A href='eASEE:DCT_MFA2,1488932'>20210421a_AU42_L2_d2h421bt06ux_eisende.PAR; 0 (PAR)</A>
<--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

- **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** Results:

```
1488932
```

- In **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** get your string in clip-board:

```
 $(Get-Clipboard|Foreach{$_.split('\''>*.,')[2]})|Set-clipboard
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. I updated the main Question above.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for comment/test, and add full file/layout string in your polst..

Comment: @Michael Plz, test last edit...